# fail2ban not manipulate iptables

Tags: iptables, fail2ban

i googled some articles like"how to install fail2ban on ubuntu 20.04",
none of them mentioned my situation.

my env: new ubuntu 20.04 installation on vmware player.straight install fail2ban.

i think fail2ban should insert some rules in iptables,but the output shows fail2ban did nothing.

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

this is /var/log/fail2ban.log  https://pastebin.com/vKiLyTC4

any idea why fail2ban just do nothing?

Comment: Please give more information. Show us that fail2ban should have done something by manually looking at `/var/log/auth.log`, extracting and example of 5 ssh login attempts, from the same source IP address, after you started fail2ban and adding that information to your question.

Comment: thanx for replay,i dont know that log file is a key checkpoint.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same expectations as Ivan - that is, I expected fail2ban to create the chains and insert the rules to reference those chains, directly when fail2ban started. I believe this used to be the default behavior as well.

After struggling to figure out what's wrong for about an hour, I found that there's nothing wrong at all. Fail2ban now appears to work just-in-time, creating the chain and inserting the rule referencing that chain only when an IP gets banned.

1. Start fail2ban: `systemctl start fail2ban.service`
2. Observe no chains / rules added in `iptables -nvL`
3. Manually ban an IP: `fail2ban-client set recidive banip 1.2.3.4`
4. Observe the chain / rule added in `iptables -nvL`

Answer (score 0):

thanks to Doug Smythies,

ubuntu 16.04 is the only one i have ever used.after installed fail2ban,iptables -S output:

```
    -P INPUT ACCEPT
    -P FORWARD ACCEPT
    -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
    -N f2b-sshd
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j f2b-sshd
    -A f2b-sshd -j RETURN
```

im expecting fail2ban@ubuntu 20.04 have the same behavior.